# perl find lines containing string 1 then extract character between string 2 and 3

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, file

Hi I have written the following script to extract lines that contain one of a list of strings:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_name = shift @ARGV;

open(my $file, '<', $file_name) or die $!;

while (<$file>) {
   print $_ if /(textsem:DiseaseDisorderMention|textsem:SignSymptomMention)/;
}

close $file;
```

which results in:

```
<textsem:DiseaseDisorderMention xmi:id="278" sofa="6" begin="56" end="65" id="6" ontologyConceptArr="221 251 261 231 241" typeID="2" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="1"/>
<textsem:DiseaseDisorderMention xmi:id="421" sofa="6" begin="18" end="26" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="359 399 369 339 309 349 389 379 319 329" typeID="2" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
<textsem:SignSymptomMention xmi:id="520" sofa="6" begin="38" end="55" id="2" ontologyConceptArr="492 462 472 502 452 482" typeID="3" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
<textsem:SignSymptomMention xmi:id="563" sofa="6" begin="45" end="52" id="5" ontologyConceptArr="550" typeID="3" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
<textsem:SignSymptomMention xmi:id="606" sofa="6" begin="45" end="55" id="4" ontologyConceptArr="593" typeID="3" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
<textsem:SignSymptomMention xmi:id="704" sofa="6" begin="38" end="52" id="3" ontologyConceptArr="686 666 676 646 656 636" typeID="3" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
<textsem:SignSymptomMention xmi:id="758" sofa="6" begin="38" end="65" id="1" ontologyConceptArr="744 734" typeID="3" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
```

Where you can see that I am extracting some xml (well actually it's an xmi file which doesn't seem to play nice with XML::Simple).

Instead of just printing these lines, I would like to instead store some of the attributes like `id="278`, `sofa="6"`,`begin="56"` or `segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT"` into an array of arrays i.e bit like doing

```
@mentions =  ( [ 278, 6, 56, "SIMPLE_SEGMENT" ],
               [ 421, 6, 18, "SIMPLE SEGMENT" ],
               [ 520, 6, 38, "SIMPLE SEGMENT" ]
                      .
                      .
                      .
             );
```

I just don't know how to do this programatically. How would I do this?

full XMI file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xmi:XMI xmlns:syntax="http:///org/apache/ctakes/typesystem/type/syntax.ecore" xmlns:refsem="http:///org/apache/ctakes/typesystem/type/refsem.ecore" xmlns:cas="http:///uima/cas.ecore" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:util="http:///org/apache/ctakes/typesystem/type/util.ecore" xmlns:textspan="http:///org/apache/ctakes/typesystem/type/textspan.ecore" xmlns:assertion="http:///org/apache/ctakes/typesystem/type/temporary/assertion.ecore" xmlns:structured="http:///org/apache/ctakes/typesystem/type/structured.ecore" xmlns:relation="http:///org/apache/ctakes/typesystem/type/relation.ecore" xmlns:textsem="http:///org/apache/ctakes/typesystem/type/textsem.ecore" xmlns:type="http:///org/apache/ctakes/drugner/type.ecore" xmlns:tcas="http:///uima/tcas.ecore" xmi:version="2.0">
    <cas:NULL xmi:id="0"/>
    <cas:Sofa xmi:id="6" sofaNum="1" sofaID="_InitialView" mimeType="text" sofaString="Mary doesn't have epilepsy, she has a family history of migraines."/>
    <tcas:DocumentAnnotation xmi:id="1" sofa="6" begin="0" end="66" language="en"/>
    <textspan:Segment xmi:id="13" sofa="6" begin="0" end="66" id="SIMPLE_SEGMENT"/>
    <textspan:Sentence xmi:id="19" sofa="6" begin="0" end="66" sentenceNumber="0"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="25" sofa="6" begin="0" end="4" tokenNumber="0" normalizedForm="Mary" partOfSpeech="NNP" capitalization="1" numPosition="0" canonicalForm="Mary"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="37" sofa="6" begin="5" end="9" tokenNumber="1" normalizedForm="do" partOfSpeech="VBZ" capitalization="0" numPosition="0" canonicalForm="do"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="57" sofa="6" begin="13" end="17" tokenNumber="3" normalizedForm="have" partOfSpeech="VB" capitalization="0" numPosition="0" canonicalForm="have"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="69" sofa="6" begin="18" end="26" tokenNumber="4" normalizedForm="epilepsy" partOfSpeech="NN" capitalization="0" numPosition="0" canonicalForm="epilepsy"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="89" sofa="6" begin="28" end="31" tokenNumber="6" normalizedForm="she" partOfSpeech="PRP" capitalization="0" numPosition="0" canonicalForm="she"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="101" sofa="6" begin="32" end="35" tokenNumber="7" normalizedForm="HA" partOfSpeech="VBZ" capitalization="0" numPosition="0" canonicalForm="HA"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="113" sofa="6" begin="36" end="37" tokenNumber="8" normalizedForm="A" partOfSpeech="DT" capitalization="0" numPosition="0" canonicalForm="A"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="125" sofa="6" begin="38" end="44" tokenNumber="9" normalizedForm="family" partOfSpeech="NN" capitalization="0" numPosition="0" canonicalForm="family"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="137" sofa="6" begin="45" end="52" tokenNumber="10" normalizedForm="history" partOfSpeech="NN" capitalization="0" numPosition="0" canonicalForm="history"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="149" sofa="6" begin="53" end="55" tokenNumber="11" normalizedForm="of" partOfSpeech="IN" capitalization="0" numPosition="0"/>
    <syntax:WordToken xmi:id="161" sofa="6" begin="56" end="65" tokenNumber="12" normalizedForm="migraine" partOfSpeech="NNS" capitalization="0" numPosition="0" canonicalForm="migraine"/>
    <syntax:ContractionToken xmi:id="49" sofa="6" begin="9" end="12" tokenNumber="2" normalizedForm="n't" partOfSpeech="RB"/>
    <syntax:PunctuationToken xmi:id="81" sofa="6" begin="26" end="27" tokenNumber="5" normalizedForm="," partOfSpeech=","/>
    <syntax:PunctuationToken xmi:id="173" sofa="6" begin="65" end="66" tokenNumber="13" normalizedForm="." partOfSpeech="."/>
    <syntax:NP xmi:id="181" sofa="6" begin="0" end="4" chunkType="NP"/>
    <syntax:NP xmi:id="191" sofa="6" begin="18" end="26" chunkType="NP"/>
    <syntax:NP xmi:id="201" sofa="6" begin="28" end="31" chunkType="NP"/>
    <syntax:NP xmi:id="211" sofa="6" begin="36" end="65" chunkType="NP"/>
    <syntax:NP xmi:id="216" sofa="6" begin="56" end="65" chunkType="NP"/>
    <syntax:VP xmi:id="186" sofa="6" begin="5" end="17" chunkType="VP"/>
    <syntax:VP xmi:id="206" sofa="6" begin="32" end="35" chunkType="VP"/>
    <syntax:O xmi:id="196" sofa="6" begin="26" end="27" chunkType="O"/>
    <textsem:DiseaseDisorderMention xmi:id="278" sofa="6" begin="56" end="65" id="6" ontologyConceptArr="221 251 261 231 241" typeID="2" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="1"/>
    <textsem:DiseaseDisorderMention xmi:id="421" sofa="6" begin="18" end="26" id="0" ontologyConceptArr="359 399 369 339 309 349 389 379 319 329" typeID="2" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:SignSymptomMention xmi:id="520" sofa="6" begin="38" end="55" id="2" ontologyConceptArr="492 462 472 502 452 482" typeID="3" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:SignSymptomMention xmi:id="563" sofa="6" begin="45" end="52" id="5" ontologyConceptArr="550" typeID="3" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:SignSymptomMention xmi:id="606" sofa="6" begin="45" end="55" id="4" ontologyConceptArr="593" typeID="3" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:SignSymptomMention xmi:id="704" sofa="6" begin="38" end="52" id="3" ontologyConceptArr="686 666 676 646 656 636" typeID="3" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
    <textsem:SignSymptomMention xmi:id="758" sofa="6" begin="38" end="65" id="1" ontologyConceptArr="744 734" typeID="3" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="0"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="792" sofa="6" begin="0" end="66" id="0"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="806" sofa="6" begin="0" end="4" id="1" form="Mary" lemma="mary" cpostag="NNP" postag="NNP" feats="_" head="848" deprel="nsubj" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="820" sofa="6" begin="5" end="9" id="2" form="does" lemma="do" cpostag="VBZ" postag="VBZ" feats="_" head="848" deprel="aux" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="834" sofa="6" begin="9" end="12" id="3" form="n't" lemma="not" cpostag="RB" postag="RB" feats="_" head="848" deprel="neg" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="848" sofa="6" begin="13" end="17" id="4" form="have" lemma="have" cpostag="VB" postag="VB" feats="_" head="904" deprel="ccomp" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="862" sofa="6" begin="18" end="26" id="5" form="epilepsy" lemma="epilepsy" cpostag="NN" postag="NN" feats="_" head="848" deprel="dobj" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="876" sofa="6" begin="26" end="27" id="6" form="," lemma="," cpostag="," postag="," feats="_" head="904" deprel="punct" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="890" sofa="6" begin="28" end="31" id="7" form="she" lemma="she" cpostag="PRP" postag="PRP" feats="_" head="904" deprel="nsubj" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="904" sofa="6" begin="32" end="35" id="8" form="has" lemma="have" cpostag="VBZ" postag="VBZ" feats="_" head="792" deprel="root" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="918" sofa="6" begin="36" end="37" id="9" form="a" lemma="a" cpostag="DT" postag="DT" feats="_" head="946" deprel="det" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="932" sofa="6" begin="38" end="44" id="10" form="family" lemma="family" cpostag="NN" postag="NN" feats="_" head="946" deprel="nn" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="946" sofa="6" begin="45" end="52" id="11" form="history" lemma="history" cpostag="NN" postag="NN" feats="_" head="904" deprel="dobj" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="960" sofa="6" begin="53" end="55" id="12" form="of" lemma="of" cpostag="IN" postag="IN" feats="_" head="946" deprel="prep" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="974" sofa="6" begin="56" end="65" id="13" form="migraines" lemma="migraine" cpostag="NNS" postag="NNS" feats="_" head="960" deprel="pobj" pdeprel="_"/>
    <syntax:ConllDependencyNode xmi:id="988" sofa="6" begin="65" end="66" id="14" form="." lemma="." cpostag="." postag="." feats="_" head="904" deprel="punct" pdeprel="_"/>
    <textsem:Predicate xmi:id="1002" sofa="6" begin="5" end="9" relations="" frameSet="do.01"/>
    <textsem:Predicate xmi:id="1009" sofa="6" begin="13" end="17" relations="1080 1090 1100" frameSet="have.03"/>
    <textsem:Predicate xmi:id="1016" sofa="6" begin="32" end="35" relations="1053 1063" frameSet="have.03"/>
    <textsem:SemanticArgument xmi:id="1023" sofa="6" begin="0" end="4" relation="1080" label="A0"/>
    <textsem:SemanticArgument xmi:id="1029" sofa="6" begin="9" end="12" relation="1090" label="AM-NEG"/>
    <textsem:SemanticArgument xmi:id="1035" sofa="6" begin="18" end="26" relation="1100" label="A1"/>
    <textsem:SemanticArgument xmi:id="1041" sofa="6" begin="28" end="31" relation="1053" label="A0"/>
    <textsem:SemanticArgument xmi:id="1047" sofa="6" begin="45" end="52" relation="1063" label="A1"/>
    <textsem:SemanticRoleRelation xmi:id="1053" id="0" category="A0" discoveryTechnique="0" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" predicate="1016" argument="1041"/>
    <textsem:SemanticRoleRelation xmi:id="1063" id="0" category="A1" discoveryTechnique="0" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" predicate="1016" argument="1047"/>
    <textsem:SemanticRoleRelation xmi:id="1080" id="0" category="A0" discoveryTechnique="0" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" predicate="1009" argument="1023"/>
    <textsem:SemanticRoleRelation xmi:id="1090" id="0" category="AM-NEG" discoveryTechnique="0" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" predicate="1009" argument="1029"/>
    <textsem:SemanticRoleRelation xmi:id="1100" id="0" category="A1" discoveryTechnique="0" confidence="0.0" polarity="0" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" predicate="1009" argument="1035"/>
    <cas:NonEmptyFSList xmi:id="1073" head="1053" tail="1076"/>
    <cas:NonEmptyFSList xmi:id="1076" head="1063" tail="1079"/>
    <cas:NonEmptyFSList xmi:id="1110" head="1080" tail="1113"/>
    <cas:NonEmptyFSList xmi:id="1113" head="1090" tail="1116"/>
    <cas:NonEmptyFSList xmi:id="1116" head="1100" tail="1119"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1334" sofa="6" begin="0" end="4" nodeType="NNP" nodeValue="Mary" leaf="true" parent="1570" headIndex="0" index="0" tokenIndex="0"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1347" sofa="6" begin="5" end="9" nodeType="VBZ" nodeValue="does" leaf="true" parent="1587" headIndex="0" index="1" tokenIndex="1"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1360" sofa="6" begin="9" end="12" nodeType="RB" nodeValue="n't" leaf="true" parent="1587" headIndex="0" index="2" tokenIndex="2"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1373" sofa="6" begin="13" end="17" nodeType="VB" nodeValue="have" leaf="true" parent="1605" headIndex="0" index="3" tokenIndex="3"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1386" sofa="6" begin="18" end="26" nodeType="NN" nodeValue="epilepsy" leaf="true" parent="1622" headIndex="0" index="4" tokenIndex="4"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1399" sofa="6" begin="26" end="27" nodeType="," nodeValue="," leaf="true" parent="1534" headIndex="0" index="5" tokenIndex="5"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1412" sofa="6" begin="28" end="31" nodeType="PRP" nodeValue="she" leaf="true" parent="1655" headIndex="0" index="6" tokenIndex="6"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1425" sofa="6" begin="32" end="35" nodeType="VBZ" nodeValue="has" leaf="true" parent="1672" headIndex="0" index="7" tokenIndex="7"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1438" sofa="6" begin="36" end="37" nodeType="DT" nodeValue="a" leaf="true" parent="1706" headIndex="0" index="8" tokenIndex="8"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1451" sofa="6" begin="38" end="44" nodeType="NN" nodeValue="family" leaf="true" parent="1706" headIndex="0" index="9" tokenIndex="9"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1464" sofa="6" begin="45" end="52" nodeType="NN" nodeValue="history" leaf="true" parent="1706" headIndex="0" index="10" tokenIndex="10"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1477" sofa="6" begin="53" end="55" nodeType="IN" nodeValue="of" leaf="true" parent="1724" headIndex="0" index="11" tokenIndex="11"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1490" sofa="6" begin="56" end="65" nodeType="NNS" nodeValue="migraines" leaf="true" parent="1741" headIndex="0" index="12" tokenIndex="12"/>
    <syntax:TerminalTreebankNode xmi:id="1503" sofa="6" begin="65" end="66" nodeType="." nodeValue="." leaf="true" parent="1534" headIndex="0" index="13" tokenIndex="13"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1534" sofa="6" begin="0" end="66" nodeType="S" leaf="false" parent="1516" children="1553 1399 1638 1503" headIndex="7"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1553" sofa="6" begin="0" end="26" nodeType="S" leaf="false" parent="1534" children="1570 1587" headIndex="1"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1570" sofa="6" begin="0" end="4" nodeType="NP" leaf="false" parent="1553" children="1334" headIndex="0">
        <nodeTags>SBJ</nodeTags>
    </syntax:TreebankNode>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1587" sofa="6" begin="5" end="26" nodeType="VP" leaf="false" parent="1553" children="1347 1360 1605" headIndex="1"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1605" sofa="6" begin="13" end="26" nodeType="VP" leaf="false" parent="1587" children="1373 1622" headIndex="3"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1622" sofa="6" begin="18" end="26" nodeType="NP" leaf="false" parent="1605" children="1386" headIndex="4"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1638" sofa="6" begin="28" end="65" nodeType="S" leaf="false" parent="1534" children="1655 1672" headIndex="7"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1655" sofa="6" begin="28" end="31" nodeType="NP" leaf="false" parent="1638" children="1412" headIndex="6">
        <nodeTags>SBJ</nodeTags>
    </syntax:TreebankNode>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1672" sofa="6" begin="32" end="65" nodeType="VP" leaf="false" parent="1638" children="1425 1689" headIndex="7"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1689" sofa="6" begin="36" end="65" nodeType="NP" leaf="false" parent="1672" children="1706 1724" headIndex="10"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1706" sofa="6" begin="36" end="52" nodeType="NP" leaf="false" parent="1689" children="1438 1451 1464" headIndex="10"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1724" sofa="6" begin="53" end="65" nodeType="PP" leaf="false" parent="1689" children="1477 1741" headIndex="11"/>
    <syntax:TreebankNode xmi:id="1741" sofa="6" begin="56" end="65" nodeType="NP" leaf="false" parent="1724" children="1490" headIndex="12"/>
    <syntax:TopTreebankNode xmi:id="1516" sofa="6" begin="0" end="66" nodeType="TOP" leaf="false" children="1534" headIndex="0" treebankParse="(TOP (S (S (NP-SBJ (NNP Mary)) (VP (VBZ does)(RB n't) (VP (VB have) (NP (NN epilepsy)))))(, ,) (S (NP-SBJ (PRP she)) (VP (VBZ has) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN family) (NN history)) (PP (IN of) (NP (NNS migraines))))))(. .)))" terminals="1334 1347 1360 1373 1386 1399 1412 1425 1438 1451 1464 1477 1490 1503"/>
    <cas:EmptyFSList xmi:id="1119"/>
    <cas:EmptyFSList xmi:id="1079"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="734" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="137741002" oid="137741002#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0455393" tui="T033" preferredText="FH: Migraine"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="744" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="160342001" oid="160342001#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0455393" tui="T033" preferredText="FH: Migraine"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="636" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="57177007" oid="57177007#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="656" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="276502004" oid="276502004#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="646" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="160470003" oid="160470003#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="676" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="266909004" oid="266909004#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="666" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="137863003" oid="137863003#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="686" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="137667000" oid="137667000#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="593" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="392521001" oid="392521001#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0262926" tui="T033" preferredText="Medical History"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="550" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="392521001" oid="392521001#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0262926" tui="T033" preferredText="Medical History"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="482" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="137863003" oid="137863003#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="452" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="57177007" oid="57177007#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="502" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="137667000" oid="137667000#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="472" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="276502004" oid="276502004#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="462" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="160470003" oid="160470003#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="492" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="266909004" oid="266909004#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0241889" tui="T033" preferredText="Family history"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="329" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="246545002" oid="246545002#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0014544" tui="T047" preferredText="Epilepsy"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="319" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="267593008" oid="267593008#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0014544" tui="T047" preferredText="Epilepsy"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="379" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="271788002" oid="271788002#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0014544" tui="T047" preferredText="Epilepsy"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="389" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="193026007" oid="193026007#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0014544" tui="T047" preferredText="Epilepsy"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="349" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="128613002" oid="128613002#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0014544" tui="T047" preferredText="Epilepsy"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="309" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="155036009" oid="155036009#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0014544" tui="T047" preferredText="Epilepsy"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="339" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="267698007" oid="267698007#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0014544" tui="T047" preferredText="Epilepsy"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="369" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="155045005" oid="155045005#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0014544" tui="T047" preferredText="Epilepsy"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="399" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="313307000" oid="313307000#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0014544" tui="T047" preferredText="Epilepsy"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="359" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="84757009" oid="84757009#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0014544" tui="T047" preferredText="Epilepsy"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="241" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="267699004" oid="267699004#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0149931" tui="T047" preferredText="Migraine Disorders"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="231" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="193041007" oid="193041007#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0149931" tui="T047" preferredText="Migraine Disorders"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="261" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="155048007" oid="155048007#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0149931" tui="T047" preferredText="Migraine Disorders"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="251" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="37796009" oid="37796009#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0149931" tui="T047" preferredText="Migraine Disorders"/>
    <refsem:UmlsConcept xmi:id="221" codingScheme="SNOMEDCT" code="155046006" oid="155046006#SNOMEDCT" score="0.0" disambiguated="false" cui="C0149931" tui="T047" preferredText="Migraine Disorders"/>
    <cas:View sofa="6" members="1 13 19 25 37 57 69 89 101 113 125 137 149 161 49 81 173 181 191 201 211 216 186 206 196 278 421 520 563 606 704 758 792 806 820 834 848 862 876 890 904 918 932 946 960 974 988 1002 1009 1016 1023 1029 1035 1041 1047 1053 1063 1080 1090 1100 1073 1076 1110 1113 1116 1334 1347 1360 1373 1386 1399 1412 1425 1438 1451 1464 1477 1490 1503 1534 1553 1570 1587 1605 1622 1638 1655 1672 1689 1706 1724 1741 1516"/>
</xmi:XMI>
```

Comment: Don't use XML::Simple. It's overcomplicated. You can try a different parser like XML::Twig, but you don't seem to be after structure here. If you're sure those attributes only ever contain numbers, you can just grab them with a pattern match.

Comment: Can you post a more complete XML sample? My standard answer would be to use `XML::Twig` to parse it, but I can't give you an example without some source XML.

Comment: @Sobrique - added. it is XMI, not XML though.

Comment: @simbabque - it comes directly after `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: `XML::Twig` can parse that file, so you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to parse a lot of structure from your XML document, but actually already have filtered it down to just these tags, then you can treat it as a weird text format.

Sometimes it's ok to be pragmatic, as long as you can guarantee that there are only numbers, letters and whitespace in those attributes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next unless $line =~ /(textsem:DiseaseDisorderMention|textsem:SignSymptomMention)/;
    my %attributes;
    $attributes{$1} = $2 while $line =~ m/(\w+)="([\w\s]+)"/g;

    print Dumper \%attributes;
}

__DATA__
<textsem:DiseaseDisorderMention xmi:id="278" sofa="6" begin="56" end="65" id="6" ontologyConceptArr="221 251 261 231 241" typeID="2" segmentID="SIMPLE_SEGMENT" discoveryTechnique="1" confidence="0.0" polarity="1" uncertainty="0" conditional="false" generic="false" subject="patient" historyOf="1"/>
```

This gives you:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'end' => '65',
          'id' => '6',
          'polarity' => '1',
          'discoveryTechnique' => '1',
          'uncertainty' => '0',
          'historyOf' => '1',
          'sofa' => '6',
          'typeID' => '2',
          'begin' => '56'
        };
```

You can probably take it from there.

Comment: "weird text format" was the technical term I was looking for. It does unfortunately contain attributes that are strings and I apologize for not making this clear. I will amend my question. There is some basic structure though in that all attributes are separated by `" ` (quote followed by whitespace).

Comment: @bruce updated. The real data doesn't make much different. It doesn't contain anything that makes pattern-matching it hard. Just letters, numbers and blanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's come up in comments - my answer would be "Use a parser".

XML::Twig is perfectly capable of parsing your XMI and it goes a bit like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new->parsefile ('your_file.xml'); 

my @target_keys = qw ( id sofa begin segmentID );

foreach my $thing ( $twig->get_xpath('//*[@id]') ) {
   if (  $thing->tag eq 'textsem:SignSymptomMention'
      or $thing->tag eq 'textsem:DiseaseDisorderMention' )
   {
      print $thing -> tag;
      print "$_ => " . $thing->att($_). " " for @target_keys;
      print "\n";
   }
}
```

You can accomplish the precise result you're after (although personally, I'd suggest not extracting things, and using them 'in place'):

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new->parsefile('your_file.xml'); 

my @target_keys = qw ( id sofa begin segmentID );
my @results; 

foreach my $thing ( $twig->get_xpath('//*[@id]') ) {
   if (  $thing->tag eq 'textsem:SignSymptomMention'
      or $thing->tag eq 'textsem:DiseaseDisorderMention' )
   {
      push @results, [map { $thing -> att($_) } @target_keys]; 

   }
}

print Dumper \@results;
```

Which gives:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '6',
            '6',
            '56',
            'SIMPLE_SEGMENT'
          ],
          [
            '0',
            '6',
            '18',
            'SIMPLE_SEGMENT'
          ],
          [
            '2',
            '6',
            '38',
            'SIMPLE_SEGMENT'
          ],
          [
            '5',
            '6',
            '45',
            'SIMPLE_SEGMENT'
          ],
          [
            '4',
            '6',
            '45',
            'SIMPLE_SEGMENT'
          ],
          [
            '3',
            '6',
            '38',
            'SIMPLE_SEGMENT'
          ],
          [
            '1',
            '6',
            '38',
            'SIMPLE_SEGMENT'
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: Since I hardly ever actually use XML::Twig and you seem to use it a lot more... Can you explain whether there is a benefit of your approach of not using `twig_handlers` for this over the version I added in my second answer?

Comment: There's not much in it IMO. I feel handlers are slightly less intuitive if you don't need the parse/purge/rewrite capability they offer, but that's a personal opinion rather than a firm fact.

Comment: Thank you. Since I didn't know about the `get_xpath` method until now I feel the opposite. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach using [XML::Twig](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) and twig handlers for the two tags you want to parse. It's possible to build an xpath expression to match both tags, but I prefer just assigning the same code reference twice as it's clearer and easier to read.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Printer;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        'textsem:DiseaseDisorderMention' => \&match,
        'textsem:SignSymptomMention' => \&match,
    }
)->parse(\*DATA);

my @mentions;
sub match {
    push @mentions, [ 
        $_->att('xmi:id'), 
        $_->att('sofa'), 
        $_->att('begin'), 
        $_->att('segmentID'),
    ];
}

p @mentions;

__DATA__
...
```

Alternatively you can also use a shorter `map` based approach for the handler.

```
sub match {
    my ($t, $e) = @_;
    push @mentions, [ map { $e->att($_) } qw(xmi:id sofa begin segmentID) ];
}
```

In both cases the output is as follows:

```
[
    [0] [
        [0] 278,
        [1] 6,
        [2] 56,
        [3] "SIMPLE_SEGMENT"
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] 421,
        [1] 6,
        [2] 18,
        [3] "SIMPLE_SEGMENT"
    ],
    [2] [
        [0] 520,
        [1] 6,
        [2] 38,
        [3] "SIMPLE_SEGMENT"
    ],
    [3] [
        [0] 563,
        [1] 6,
        [2] 45,
        [3] "SIMPLE_SEGMENT"
    ],
    [4] [
        [0] 606,
        [1] 6,
        [2] 45,
        [3] "SIMPLE_SEGMENT"
    ],
    [5] [
        [0] 704,
        [1] 6,
        [2] 38,
        [3] "SIMPLE_SEGMENT"
    ],
    [6] [
        [0] 758,
        [1] 6,
        [2] 38,
        [3] "SIMPLE_SEGMENT"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [XML::SAX](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-SAX-0.99/SAX.pm) package:

Main:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
use XML::SAX::ParserFactory;
use MyHandler;

my $handler = MyHandler->new();
my $parser = XML::SAX::ParserFactory->parser(Handler => $handler);

$parser->parse_uri('./yourxmlfile.xml');

print Dumper($MyHandler::result);
```

package: `MyHandler.pm`

```
package MyHandler;
use strict;
use warnings;
use base qw(XML::SAX::Base);

our $result = [];

sub start_element {
    my ($self, $data) = @_;

    if ($data->{'Name'} =~ /^textsem:(?:DiseaseDisorderMention|SignSymptomMention)$/) {
        push $result, [ $data->{'Attributes'}->{'{http://www.omg.org/XMI}id'}->{'Value'}, 
                        $data->{'Attributes'}->{'{}sofa'}->{'Value'},
                        $data->{'Attributes'}->{'{}begin'}->{'Value'},
                        $data->{'Attributes'}->{'{}segmentID'}->{'Value'} ];
    }
}

1;
```